# jQuery animation order before/after load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to slide my main container `#main` up before loading the new content inside and then slide down again when the load is complete. This seems to work on the first click but on subsequent clicks the content loads instantly before the `slideUp` and `slideDown` animations begin.

```
$("#access a").address(function() {  
    $("div#main").slideUp(1111).delay(1200).load($(this).attr('href') + ' #menudropdown, #contentbody', function(){  
        $("div#main").slideDown(1111);          
    });

    var current = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + location.pathname;
    if (base + '/' != current) {
        var diff = current.replace(base, '');
        location = base + '/#' + diff;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$("#access a").address(function() {
    var mainDiv = $("div#main");
    var loadLink = $(this).attr('href');
    mainDiv.slideUp(1111,function(){
        mainDiv.load( loadLink + ' #menudropdown, #contentbody', function(){  
            mainDiv.slideDown(1111);
        });       
    });
    // your other code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the ready event on slideUp?

```
 $("div#main").slideUp(1111, function () {
   $(this).load($("#access a").attr('href') + ' #menudropdown, #contentbody', function(){  
    $("div#main").slideDown(1111);
   });
 });
```

Also I would suggest to hide the content before loading by using the full ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
      url: $("#access a").attr('href'),
      success: function (data) {
         $("div#main").slideUp(function () {
            $(this).hide().empty().append(data.find('#menudropdown, #contentbody')).slideDown();
         });
       }
    });
```

Comment: Your first code block incorrectly selects the `href` attribute of `div#main` instead of the `a`. The second block just seems a little unnecessary as the `.load()` function was specifically designed for the situation the OP is in.